# How to integrate Identity Server's users with Slack and how to create a new Slack Work-Space

Tags: .net, identityserver4, slack, slack-api

I have my user system implemented with Identity Server 4 (.NET). My requirement is when a new user was created, I need to create a Workspace (if not) and a new user with the same email in Slack and add this user into this workspace.

So my questions is

1. Is there anyway or something like API to migrate/create user into Slack ?
2. Is there anyway to create a new Work-Space without come into Slack Website ?

Thank very much for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two distinct workflows here. One is creating a user, which you can do with the [SCIM API](https://api.slack.com/admins/scim), assuming you're on a Business+ or Enterprise Grid plan.

The other thing you want to do is create a Workspace. For this, you'd need to use the Admin API method [`admin.teams.create`](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.teams.create). Using this requires a Enterprise Grid plan, because you can only use the API to create workspaces **inside** a Grid you control. You can't create completely new workspaces outside of a grid using an API.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, after a lot of research, I found the only one way to do my requirement is an Enterprise Grid / Business plan.